# Почему в Битрикс не подключаются js файлы через Asset?

Tags: битрикс

В шаблоне Битрикс не могу подключить js файлы через Asset, пишу вот так

```
<?php use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset; ?>
<?php Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/js/script.js'); ?>
```

При подключении css или просто string все нормально подключается, но скрипты работают только если подключаю вот так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

Почему не работает подключение через Asset?

Comment: Если скрипты обращаются к каким-то элементам DOM, а Asset вставляет скрипты в head, то понятно, что скрипты пытаются обратиться к элементам, которые ещё не успели создаться. Необходимо использовать ```$(document).ready( function(){...})``` или, если на чистом js, ```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){...})```

Answer (score -1):

В настройках модуля нужно было поставить галочку -
Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы: